# Clockwise animation of circle

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i am trying to do such animation https://streamable.com/dvg6m but i just cannot figure out how to do it with Animated/Animatable components. Maybe there are other components of doing such animation or maybe there is a  different way to somehow do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the code that you have done so far

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have any code because the only thing i can do is place static circle (white inside) with black border.